# The Electromagnetic Energy and Momentum Conservation in curved space-time

Tags: electromagnetism, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Can someone please show me the formalisms of the energy and the momentum conservation in the curved space-time for electromagnetic?
I know it's going to be two equations.
but I couldn't find them anywhere and I couldn't calculate them.

Answer (score 1):

In curved spacetime we use tensors, so the conservation of energy and the conservation of momentum are parts of the same equation. The equation is $$\nabla_\nu \left(T_{\mu\gamma}\ g^{\gamma \nu}\ \frac{\sqrt{-g}}{c}\right)+ F_{\mu\nu}\ J^{\nu}=0$$ Where $T$ is the electromagnetic stress energy tensor, $g$ is the metric, $F$ is the electromagnetic field tensor, and $J$ is the four-current density.

The stress energy tensor can be written in terms of the electromagnetic field tensor and the metric as follows $$T_{\mu \nu}=-\frac{1}{\mu_0}\left( F_{\mu\alpha}\ g^{\alpha\beta}\  F_{\beta\nu}-\frac{1}{4}g_{\mu\nu}\ F_{\sigma\alpha}\ g^{\alpha \beta}\ F_{\beta\rho}\ g^{\rho\sigma}\right)$$

For more details see Wikipedia's entry on [Maxwell's equations in curved spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations_in_curved_spacetime).

Comment: Thank you so much very appreciate it! 
but I wonder if I can found them calculated because i can't and i need the results.